# SpringBoot dependency jars not found on Tomcat 8

Tags: spring-boot, jar, tomcat8

Using springboot 1.5.3 and tomcat 8 and 8.5.  I have a custom spring boot project im using as a dependency.  it's just repo classes.  From my main class, I've add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.swisher</groupId>
        <artifactId>product-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml file.   It works just fine, but when I package the project as a deployable war file and push to Tomcat 8 or 8.5, my dependency project model classes are not visible to my controller.

2017-06-05 14:21:57.157 ERROR 5184 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/] due to exception [com/swisher/pc/model/Person]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/swisher/pc/model/Person
    at com.swisher.pc.controllers.CatalogController.index(CatalogController.java:75) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

I've tried using

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={ "com.swisher", "com.swisher.pc"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.swisher", "com.swisher.pc"})`

but still not working.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: How do you package your application? Do you use the default maven spring boot plugin or do you do some custom stuff with the assembly or other maven plugins?

Comment: I'm using the default maven to build war file. I believe it's a classpath issue and not a problem with package scanning.  if I have a spring boot app that's used as a dependency, are there specific configuration that's needed?

Comment: From within Spring Suite... if I run project as Spring Boot.  it works fine.  And it can resolve the dependency class.. which is a simple pojo.  Mapped "{[/goodbye]}" onto public com.test.model.Person com.example.demo.controller.MainController.getPersonObj().   But when I run the project using mvn spring-boot:run.  I'm getting Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/model/Person @user3780135

Comment: Do you use the Spring Boot application as a dependency in another Maven project? That doesn't work then because of the way how the Spring Boot plugin packages the class files in the resulting JAR/WAR. If you need those classes as a dependency, move them to another module, which you then can use as dependency.

Comment: Thanks! This article further explains [link]https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6792#issuecomment-243564648  This is due to the change in layout of executable jars in Spring Boot 1.4. Application classes are now packaging in BOOT-INF/classes  So this entry in the pom does the trick.

Comment: `  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
       `

Comment: then use mvn package spring-boot:repackage

Answer (score 0):

This article further explains [link]github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/… This is due to the change in layout of executable jars in Spring Boot 1.4. Application classes are now packaging in BOOT-INF/classes So this entry in the pom does the trick`

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>repackage</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <classifier>exec</classifier>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                </executions>
     </plugin>
```

`

Then use: mvn package spring-boot:repackage.  Followed by mvn install.